# I am Getting Stuck when using WordPress URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I am newbie to WordPress, and I want to make some changes in WordPress Theme. I want to open Image in new theme file. I already created new theme file with the name "newfile.php".

The Code I am using is:

```
$image = get_field('image');
$picture = $image['sizes']['large'];

$file = get_field('download');
$filename = $file['filename'];
 $fileurl = $file['url'];

<a href="<?php echo  $fileurl; ?>">
 <img src="<?php echo $picture; ?>" class="img-fluid">
</a>
```

I want to echo in new theme file instead of directly opening the image.

Comment: When you echo the picture var what's the exact value?

Comment: $image = get_field('image');
$picture = $image['sizes']['large'];

Comment: All I want is to add new Them file URL over here:
<a href="<?php echo  $fileurl; ?>">

Comment: I understand your question but you need to be sure of what value is being outputted in the URL. That is why I am asking... Is it a valid URL?

Comment: Yes it is a valid url, but I want to redirect to new theme file instead of just picture.

Comment: OK. Pass the theme file to the URL with a parameter and show the picture on the new file based on your condition.

Comment: If you need more information to clearly understand my question, here is my website: [pakworkforce](https://pakworkforce.com)

Comment: Where can i try the feature on the site..

Comment: Actually I want to open this image https://pakworkforce.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Jobs-at-Waleed-City-Lahore-Authority-WCLA-Lahore..png in another theme file, where I can also put some content.

Comment: Sorry for inconvience. I might not explain what exactly my problem is. but thank you for your time.